# Plugin Placemark snap to location grid size too large

Tags: google-earth-plugin

When trying to add a placemark to the plugin via the API. The place mark positions itself to an invisible grid that seems to be about a metre square.

My application needs accuracy to 10cm, does anyone know how to stop the place mark snapping to a grid and positioning at the mouse pointer location exactly???

Comment: nothing. I cant find any properties or methods on the api that allows me to set a local grid size. I find it odd that there is a grid??  the javascript call is  :

Comment: var placemark = g_gex.dom.addLineStringPlacemark([], {
        style: {
            line: { width: 4, color: '99000099' }
        }
    });

when the icon folows the mouice cursor, it does not follow exactly but snaps to a hidden grid.

Comment: using extensions-0.2.1.js - http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Can you show an example of the placemark? Without seeing it is hard to say but I would guess that you are probably defining its coordinates using 5 decimal places. This would account for the "invisible grid that seems to be about a metre square."

> My application needs accuracy to 10cm

The Google Earth and Maps APIs work with coordinates with an accuracy of six decimal places. This provides a precision of around 11 cm around the equator. The further you move from the equator the greater the inaccuracy. So you can't have accuracy to 10cm, at best it will be 11 cm at equatorial latitudes.

You can use the following table to give a rough an idea of how decimal places in the coordinates relate to precision on the earth. Again, the precision will fall-off the further you move from the equator.

```
Accuracy of decimal coordinates at the equator

0   1.0         111 km
1   0.1         11.1 km
2   0.01        1.11 km
3   0.001       111 m
4   0.0001      11.1 m
5   0.00001     1.11 m  * (What I think you are using now.)
6   0.000001    0.111 m * (The highest accuracy possible in the api.)
7   0.0000001   1.11 cm
8   0.00000001  1.11 mm
```